# How can i find the size of an array in symfony

Tags: php

I want to have the size of an array in symfony (in the controller),but i couldn't,
Thank you for showing me how can i find it.
*I'm using symfony 3.4
 this is my controller function

```
$session = new Session();
$products=$session->get('panier');
$i=0;
foreach($products as $p)
{
   $i++;
}

$products[$i]=$idProduit;
$session->set('panier',$products);
```

I tried with for loop but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This is a php question, not symfony. If you want to now the size of an array, use the count.

```
$size = count($products);
```